# Question about double dot product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I learn from a material that the double dot product of two tensors results in a scalar, however, from another book I saw this constitutive relation between stiffness tensor and strain tensor,
$\sigma=C:\epsilon$.

Why $\sigma$ is a tensor, it should be a scalar?

Answer (score 0):

The explicit relation is
$$
\sigma_{ij}=\sum_{k,l=1}^3C_{ijkl}\epsilon_{kl}
$$
where $C$ is a rank $4$ tensor. We can think of it as a tensor of rank $2$ for each choice of indices $i,j$
$$
\sum_{k,l=1}^3C^{(ij)}_{kl}\epsilon_{kl}=C^{(ij)}:\epsilon
$$
so the relation would be
$$
\sigma_{ij}=C^{(ij)}:\epsilon
$$
What reported is a sort of abbreviation of this